# null properties in init block kotlin

Tags: kotlin, properties, null, block, init

I do not understand why in this code values of i and s are 0 and null respectively in init{} block but in second constructor of class B these values are 200 and param2?

```
class A(override var i: Int, override var s: String) : B(200, "param2","param3") {
        init {
           println(i)
           println(s)
        }
 }



open class B(open var i: Int, open var s: String) {
    init {
        println("class B init")
        println("i in init B2 is $i")
        println("s in init B2 is $s")
    }


   constructor(i: Int, s: String, s2: String) : this(i, s) {
        println("second constructor B")
        println(" i = $i in second constructor")
        println(" s = $s in second constructor")
        println(" s2 = $s2 in second constructor")
    }

}

    
fun main() {
   val ins2 = A(500, "500S") 
}
```

results:

```
    class B init
    i in init B2 is 0
    s in init B2 is null
    second constructor B
    i = 200 in second constructor
    s = param2 in second constructor
    s2 = param3 in second constructor
    500
    500S
```

---

I need some explication please.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 warnings in that code, both `Accessing non-final property X in constructor` (one for `i` and one for `s`). Have a read here [Kotlin calling non final function in constructor works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222139/kotlin-calling-non-final-function-in-constructor-works).

That is the reason you get `0` and `null` first.

The reason you then get `200` and `param2` is because that is what you tell it to do here `B(200, "param2","param3")`.

You aren't creating it with the values from `A`, you are calling that constructor with those predefined values.

And afterwards, those values are overwritten by the `i` and `s` inside `A`.

Comment: Thanks. But it means i cant access i or s in init block? or how can i do that?